# Running hosted multisite version of wordpress

Tags: multisite

We would like to host our theme and sell recurring hosted plans in a way that all websites share the same theme and plugins with an option to add their own plugins and child themes (under one WP instance). What would be best approach to achieve this as I am concerned with WP multisite because there will be lots of websites with lots of posts and images. My main concern is scalability.

Our process: Client purchases the plan based on number of posts or space and after successful purchase client receives login details and information on how to access and manage their new WP environment. Later they can add their domain and set DNS. This is the first time we are getting into Saas recurring model with our themes and I will appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for the question&answer concept here, also it invites opinions rather than solutions. There are very large multisites (wordpress.org i.e.), there are other ways to make this possible, but are they feasible for you (using mu-plugins, having private repos for files, etc.)

Comment: You are probably correct it is bit broad and it seeks an opinion.

Comment: The thing is: have you evaluated other possible solutions? Multisite is very powerful and will probably work for this. Even scalability isn't that big of a problem. Either have one very large network or many medium sized ones. All other solutions need way more to be done by you in my opinion, multisite is kind of a already made solution

Comment: Correct. I did investigate few multisite solutions like MainWP and WPMU Dev plugins. Certainty there are many of tools to help us start. I suppose it will be trial and error kind of setup until we get it working. Thanks.